# Change row color of gridview by database Values

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I am making a application in asp.net which shows the values in gridview from the database.In database i am having a colmn named as StatusId which has a value of 1 or 2 or 3.

I tried to show the grid view rows in different color by their statusId values. But it never works. How can i do it in asp.net.

Here is my code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand Command1 = Connection.CreateCommand();
        Command1.CommandText = "Select statusColor from status where statusId=(Select statusId from fileInfo where userId=(Select userId from userInfo where email='" + Session["email"].ToString() + "'))";

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = Command1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    statusId = reader["statusColor"].ToString();
                }
             GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor = Color.FromName(statusId);           
        } 
        }


        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("gridcolor", Connection);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusId", statusId);
        com.Parameters.Add("@statusColor", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
        com.Parameters["@statusColor"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string msg = (string)com.Parameters["@statusColor"].Value;
        Connection.Close();
    }
```

What is the mistake i am doing here?

**EDIT**

I have the color codes which are stored in the database named as statusColor. I have to apply those color to these status.

Comment: Why don't you just return the status color as part of the data to which the grid is bound? Your current approach will cause a database call for *each row*.

Comment: Yeah i think that will be better way to change color for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You have `statusId` having values 1,2,3 and you are passing to Color.FromName which and 1,2,3 are not names of color you can use [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to assign different colors based on `statusId` .

```
Color rowColor = Color.Red;    
switch(statusId)
{
    case 1:
         rowColor = Color.Green;
         break;

    case 2:
         rowColor = Color.White;
         break;
    case 3:
         rowColor = Color.Blue;
         break;
}   
GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor = rowColor ;
```

Comment: What values statusId would have are they still 1,2,3 as mentioned in question?

Comment: Yeah Instead of entering into coding we can change color values from database.

Comment: Then you have to pass Red, Green etc in Color.FromName instead of 1,2,3 or use it like I told you.

Comment: This answer sets all the row color as same.

Comment: If statusID has numberic value 1,2,3 then it should change color, debug the code and check what case of switch gets executed

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way. You have to databind your gridview on either page load or a custom event (say click of a button) & not `rowDataBound` event. This event occurs when your row is bound with data & you want to change some attributes for each row (as in your case).

You can use Gridview DataBound event to assign colors in following way

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Fetch status Id for current row
        int statusId= Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"UnitsInStock"));

        switch (statusId)
       {
         case (1):
                   e.Row.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                   break;

         // other cases follow the same
       }

    }
}
```

Put the databinding code in either pageLoad or button click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grdMyQ_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grdMyQ.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (grdMyQ.Rows[i].Cells[13].Text.ToUpper() == "DISCHARGED_PROCESS")
                {
                    grdMyQ.Rows[i].BackColor = Color.Red;

                }
            }
        }
```